# Shell script - How would I compare the same files of different dat

Tags: linux, shell

I am having hundreds of files in a directory, and files are name with date as given below. 
How would I compare the same files of different date.

ex :

```
/test/
xyz-my_S1logfile.Aug.25.gz  
bhd-my_S1logfile.Aug.30.gz
ddddf-my_S2logfie.Aug.25.gz
zsed-my_S2logfie.Aug.30.gz

Compare the size of xyz-my_S1logfile.Aug.25.gz and bhd-my_S1logfile.Aug.30.gz
ddddf-my_S2logfie.Aug.25.gz and zsed-my_S2logfie.Aug.30.gz
.....
```

Comment: Why cant u use diff command ?

Comment: diff -qr one_2.txt  one_3.txt 
Files one_2.txt and one_3.txt differ, How I get the exact value ? And also for large number of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you want to find files with duplicate content within a directory. The standard way to do that is to generate a strong hash for the contents of each file. E.g. for [SHA256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) you can use the [`sha256sum`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sha256sum) tool:

```
sha256sum /my/dir/* > sha256sums.txt
```

or better yet:

```
find /my/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 sha256sum > sha256sums.txt
```

Considering that no collisions have been found for any variant of SHA-2 yet, you can be *reasonably confident* that any files with the same hash are identical. You can then use [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) and [`uniq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) to find the duplicate hashes with an occurrence count for each:

```
cat sha256sums.txt | sort | cut -b -32 | uniq -cd | sort -nr
```

You can then grep your `sha256sums.txt` file for each duplicate hash for the corresponding list of files.

Or, if you want an automated tool, you could try [FsLint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/), which [supports finding duplicate files](http://en.flossmanuals.net/fslint/ch004_duplicates/).